# Neo4j: What are the performance consequences of having many labels on a single node?

Tags: neo4j

So I imagine there's some documentation somewhere that discusses this, but I haven't found it. (I don't expect an answer to have benchmarks, just ~"in general, this is what happens")

It is my understanding that each label indexes its member's `neoID`, so adding a label to a node, and querying on that label, yields a performance benefit. But how does the performance compare if you have 10 labels on a node (vs 1 label)? What about 100 labels? Or 1000 labels? I imagine that adding more labels to a node comes with some sort of penalty? (other than the additional space the index takes up)

### Why I'm asking

Say I have a db with `:Book`, `:Person`, `:Organization`, and `:CommunityGroup` nodes. Each has a `uuid` property.

- `(:Book)-[:OWNER]->(:Person)`
- `(:Book)-[:OWNER]->(:Organization)`

`:Person` or `:Organization` nodes might own a `:Book`, but `:CommunityGroup` nodes never do. If a client passed my app an `uuid` for a book owner, I could find that node a few different ways

1. Match the node with that `uuid` which had either the `:Person` or `:Organization` labels.

   - `MATCH (:Book)-[:OWNER]->(n {uuid: $the_id}) WHERE n:Person OR n:Organization`
2. Ask the client for the node type, and match using that `uuid` and type.

   - `MATCH (:Person {uuid: $the_id})`
3. Add an `:Owner` label to the `:Person` and `:Organization` nodes

   - `MATCH (:Owner {uuid: $the_uuid})`

Option 2 must be the fastest. 3 is the overall nicest to query on. 1 minimizes extra labels + client work.

Obviously this example is small, but what if I created extra labels (like the `:Owner` label) all over the place. Is there a performance penalty for that? I could easily see a single node acquiring 10 or 20 labels, maybe more, depending on how liberal I was in applying them. The `:Owner` label is technically unnecessary, as I have the labels needed to find the node already...

Thoughts? Thanks for any feedback!

*Note: I found [this S.O. question on multiple label performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336037/neo4j-cypher-single-vs-multiple-labels-performance?rq=1), but it's only addressing a scenario with a few labels (~4), rather than 10 / 20 / 100.*

Comment: I was talking to Neo4j developer at graphconnect about this and he told me that there is a performance penalty after more than 5 labels per node. So as a rule of thumb use less than 5 labels per node

Comment: @TomažBratanič, awesome! That's exactly what I was wondering. Thanks for the info!!! (if you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct --> totally answers my question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was talking to Neo4j developer at graphconnect about this and he told me that there is a performance penalty after more than 5 labels per node. So as a rule of thumb use less than 5 labels per node.